# Hadoop Cluster SetUp : Data Node Not Working on Slave Machine

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am trying to run hadoop over two machines. below mentioned is my core-site.xml file.

10.0.x.y is working as my master machine and 10.0.x.y1 is working as slave.

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>fs.default.name</name>
        <value>hdfs://10.0.x.y:54310</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

below mentioned is my hdfs-site.xml file

```
<configuration>
        <property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>1</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.name.dir</name>
        <value>/data/hadoop-namenode-data</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.data.dir</name>
        <value>/data/hadoop-datanode-data</value>
    </property>

</configuration>
```

for the command on the 10.0.x.y start-dfs.sh --- my name node and datanode on the machine 10.0.x.y is running fine but error message on the namenode.log file is

```
2014-07-02 15:49:08,628 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: NameNode RPC up at: TPMOPW388/10.0.7.111:54310
2014-07-02 15:49:08,628 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Starting services required for active state
2014-07-02 15:49:11,268 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.DatanodeManager: Unresolved datanode registration from 10.0.40.18
2014-07-02 15:49:11,268 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:root (auth:SIMPLE) cause:org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.protocol.DisallowedDatanodeException: Datanode denied communication with namenode: DatanodeRegistration(0.0.0.0, storageID=DS-969520512-10.0.40.18-50010-1404290045109, infoPort=50075, ipcPort=50020, storageInfo=lv=-47;cid=CID-9afd9260-85c3-4018-92a6-cb391f4cfbdd;nsid=471345421;c=0)
2014-07-02 15:49:11,268 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 2 on 54310, call org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.protocol.DatanodeProtocol.registerDatanode from 10.0.40.18:57523 Call#1 Retry#0: error: org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.protocol.DisallowedDatanodeException: Datanode denied communication with namenode: DatanodeRegistration(0.0.0.0, storageID=DS-969520512-10.0.40.18-50010-1404290045109, infoPort=50075, ipcPort=50020, storageInfo=lv=-47;cid=CID-9afd9260-85c3-4018-92a6-cb391f4cfbdd;nsid=471345421;c=0)
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.protocol.DisallowedDatanodeException: Datanode denied communication with namenode: DatanodeRegistration(0.0.0.0, storageID=DS-969520512-10.0.40.18-50010-1404290045109, infoPort=50075, ipcPort=50020, storageInfo=lv=-47;cid=CID-9afd9260-85c3-4018-92a6-cb391f4cfbdd;nsid=471345421;c=0)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.DatanodeManager.registerDatanode(DatanodeManager.java:739)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.registerDatanode(FSNamesystem.java:3929)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.registerDatanode(NameNodeRpcServer.java:948)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.DatanodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.registerDatanode(DatanodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:90)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.DatanodeProtocolProtos$DatanodeProtocolService$2.callBlockingMethod(DatanodeProtocolProtos.java:24079)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:585)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:928)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2048)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2044)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1491)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2042)
```

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Probably it has to do with the hostname configuration. Check the `/etc/hosts` file and make sure you have the IP address and the hostname of both machines in each of them.

Answer (score 0):

Use value ="Number of nodes in your system" in hdfs-site.xml
and check your /etc/hosts as well.

Answer (score 0):

According to this line:

```
15:49:11,268 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:root (auth:SIMPLE) cause:org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.protocol.DisallowedDatanodeException: Datanode denied communication with namenode: DatanodeRegistration(0.0.0.0, storageID=DS-969520512-10.0.40.18-50010-1404290045109, infoPort=50075, ipcPort=50020, storageInfo=lv=-47;cid=CID-9afd9260-85c3-4018-92a6-cb391f4cfbdd;nsid=471345421;c=0)
```

It might cause by your name node can NOT access your data node with root accout via ssh.

So,

Make sure If you installed ssh and configured private key so as to login without password!